# Use Jquery fadeOut more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script allows users to upload a file using AJAX which displays a success message that then fades out. However, the message won't show a second time if they upload another file (the uploading etc does work ok).

The AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logo_save').click(function(){
            var image_name = $('#image_name').text();
             {
                  jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "save_uploaded_logo.php",
                   data: 'id='+image_name,
                   cache: false,
                   success:function(response){
                       $('#new_header_preview').html(response.logo);
                       $('#logo_upload_success').html('Image Saved').fadeOut('slow');
                   }
                 });
             }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

The portion of table used to display the message

```
<table id="report_content_practice">
   <tr>
      <td id="upload_success" style="width:370px; vertical-align:middle">
         <span id="logo_upload_success">&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're showing/fading in the message container.

Comment: You need to show your message container first before fading out, try `$('#logo_upload_success').html('Image Saved').show().fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: I want the message to only show after they click the button, and then have it fade out, which works

Comment: @jammyKam problem solved, add an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @tatty27: Great. I added an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have said, the reason is that after the first time your script runs the DOM element is hidden. You need to show the element again before running the fade otherwise you are trying to run fadeOut on an element which has is `Opacity:0`.

As I said in the comments, in your `success` function run `show()` before calling your fadeOut.

`$('#logo_upload_success').html('Image Saved').show().fadeOut('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

```
success:function(response){
    $('#new_header_preview').html(response.logo);
    $('#logo_upload_success').fadeIn().html('Image Saved').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're fading out `$('#logo_upload_success')` so this DOM-element has its opacity set to 0 when you load the Ajax for the second time, making it impossible to see the new message.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is already in place and that's the reason why you dont see any change. On the onclick function make the html value empty before sending the ajax request:

```
$('#new_header_preview').html("");$('#logo_upload_success').html("");
```